# Scala Actor sender

Tags: scala, actor

> Using sender, one can refer to the actor that sent the message that the current actor last received.

Consider the following code:

```
class HelloActor extends Actor{
    def receive = {
      case "hello" =>
        println("hello back at you")
        sender ! "hi"
      case _ => println("huh?")
    }
}

object Mian extends App{

  val system = ActorSystem("helloSystem")
  val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor")
  helloActor ! "hello"
  helloActor ! "hey"
  system.shutdown
}
```

I think the `sender` is also the `helloActor` itself, so I expected the output is:

> hello back at you
>
> huh?
>
> huh?

But the output actually is :

> hello back at you
>
> huh?

Answer (score 4):

In your example,

```
helloActor ! "hello"
```

Means send a message "hello" to 'helloActor' with the sender not specified as you are not in an actor.

If you want helloActor to be the sender, then you must specify the sender when you send the message.

```
helloActor.tell("hello", helloActor)
```

If you were inside an actor when you invoked `!` then the sender is implicitly set to that actor instance.